# Unable to login in Facebook using ngCordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ngcordova

I am building hybrid application which uses facebook login.
I have followed all the steps mentioned in [This url](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/),
however getting following error message:

[image: After facebook login this message get displayed]

Kindly help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to facebook and go to app settings page and add/configure platforms android/ios etc